# redirect stdout/stderr to function in C

Tags: c, function, redirect, stdout

I want to redirect stdout and stderr to a function and write a simple code.
fprintf is ok but when i use printf without \r, stream passed to terminal!

```
#include <stdio.h>
static ssize_t file_write(void *c, const char *buf, size_t size)
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("output.txt","w");
  fprintf(pFile, "%s", buf);
  fclose (pFile);

return size;
}

void redirect()
{
  FILE *stream;
  stream=fopencookie(NULL, "w", (cookie_io_functions_t) {(ssize_t) 0,  file_write, 0, 0});
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);
  stdout = stream;
  setbuf(stderr, NULL);
  stderr = stream;
}

int main()
{
  redirect();
  fprintf(stderr,"1-stderr test\n");
  fprintf(stdout, "2-stdout test\n");
  printf("3-printf with r test\n\r");
  printf("4-printf without r test\n");

return 0;
}
```

file "output.txt":

> 1-stderr test
>   2-stdout test
>   3-printf with r test

Terminal output:

> $ ./sample
>   4-printf without r test

Comment: 1. Sort out the indentation 2. Why not check the return value from `fopen` 3. `fprintf(pFile,buf);` - lets hope that `buf` does not contain a `%` in it!

Comment: You're using `buf` as a format string.  This will fail rather horribly if it contains any `%` characters.  Either use `fprintf(pFile, "%s", buf)` or else call `fwrite` instead of `fprintf`.

Comment: You can also call `fputs` instead of `fprintf`.  That might be simplest.

Comment: Do not even try to do that! Even if it works on a system, it could not work an another one or with another version of the standard library. My advice is to always use fprintf-fputs in such a case and let the stream be stdout when you want not to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "redirect" standard input from, or standard output to a function in your program.

You can however create a pair of pipes and replace standard input and output with these pipes, and have another function (possibly in another thread or even a child process) use the other end of the pipes to communicate with the function.

You can of course use e.g. [`setvbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) to change the buffers of `stdin` and `stdout` to a pair of buffers you provide, then you can read directly from, or write directly to the buffers like any other memory buffer (i.e. array). Not that I recommend it though, it's frail and prone to errors.

However in this case it seems like what you want is that all writing to `stdout` should go to the file. In that case (like the use of pipes) there is no standard C way of handling it, but you need to use operating system specific functionality. Then if you're on a POSIX platform (like Linux or OSX) you can tell the operating system to duplicate the underlying file descriptor for your file, and say that `STDOUT_FILNO` (which is the file descriptor used for `stdout`) is a duplicate for the file descriptor of the file you opened. Then all writes to `stdout` will be written to your file. For this you need to use [the `dup2` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html).