# Redirecting stdout/stderr *to* <QDebug>

Tags: c++, qt5, stdout, qt5.7, qdebug

I've got a GUI application that makes extensive use of `QDebug` for logging, and a message handler set up via `qInstallMessageHandler`.

However, it uses some third-party libraries that print logging info to stdout and stderr.

I'm running into some problems with compatibility. The stdout/stderr messages *do* show up in the Qt console, although they use a different buffer than the `QDebug` output and so they're printed significantly out of order relative to `QDebug` messages. Additionally, things printed to stdout/stderr don't get passed over to the message handler.

My question is: Is it possible to take stdout/stderr and redirect them *to* whatever handles `QDebug` messages (in a line-buffered mode, I guess)? If so, how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760630/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-function-in-c ? It seems you cannot.